# If $A\neq\emptyset$ there not exist the set $S$ whose element are all sets equipotent to $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Statement**

If $A\neq\emptyset$ there is no set $S$ containing all sets equipotent to $A$.

My text suggests to prove that if $S$ was a set then $\bigcup S$ would be the set of all set that is not a set but unfortunately I don't be able to use this argument. So could someone help me and show how to use this argument, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $x$ is any set not in $A$. Let $a \in A$ be a fixed element of $A$ (which exists by hypothesis that $A \neq \emptyset$. Then $(A \setminus \{a\}) \cup \{x\}$ is a set equipotent to $A$ containing $x$.

Comment: Okay so $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ would be containing all sets not in $A$, but I don't know if any set $x$ is not in $A$ so what can you say about?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The hint above suggests how to show that every set not in $A$ is in $\bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$. Do you know a set equipotent with $A$ (so an element of $\mathcal{S}$) which contains the elements of $A$?

Comment: Yes, A is surely a such set, at least so it seems to me.

Comment: Yep, so you should be able to conclude that $\bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$ contains all sets. But there is no set of all sets, contradiction.

Comment: Okay but if $x\in A$ is a set of $S$? Initially you have said "suppose $x$ is  any set not in $A$ " so that I conclude that your argument (really this not seems to me) is only valid for this genre of sets!

Comment: The only property of $x$ we used was that $x \notin A$, so the claim $x \in \bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$ has been shown for all $x \notin A$. The claim that $x \in \bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$ follows from the fact (as you observed) that $x \in A$ and $A \in \mathcal{S}$, hence $x \in \bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$ for all $x \in A$. We've now shown that $x \in \bigcup{\mathcal{S}}$ for all sets $x$, using two different arguments depending upon whether $x$ is in $A$ or not.

Comment: Okay, I have understood and therefore it seems to me that to valid your proof is not necessary to use the regularity axiom: indeed if $A\notin A$ then through your argument it follows that $A\in\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ and if $A\in A$ then for what you now observed $A\in\bigcup\mathcal{S}$. So through your argument all sets $x\notin A$ are in $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ and through what you now have observed all sets $x$ in $A$ are in $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ and for what I have said (is it correct?) $A$ is in $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ so any set could be in $\bigcup\mathcal{S}$ and this is impossible, right?